# Connect to FTPS server with Golang

Tags: go, ftps

I try to use ftp package to establish default ftps connection:

```
c, err := ftp.Dial("some_srv:some_port", ftp.DialWithTLS(nil))

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

and get astonishing self-explaining error: connect: connection refused

The documentation is awful, it's absolutely not clear, how to configure FTPS, how to combine options (for instance, timeout + TLS=true). Any ideas?)

Comment: What package are you using? Did you try supplying a `tls.Config` (which I assume is what `DialWithTLS` takes as a parameter)? Can you make a normal TLS connection, and was the connection rejected by the FTP layer?

Comment: I use github.com/jlaffaye/ftp. I use the same config in Python without any problems

Comment: You are not supplying a `tls.Config`, so how is that the same config as Python? Are you using implicit TLS or AUTH TLS? That [package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jlaffaye/ftp) has a whole list of dial options, you combine options by supplying all the options you want to use.

Comment: In Python I just pass tls=true. Here it seems I can't pass an empty configuration. Options are not exported so I can use only functions, like DialWithTls or DialWithTimeout. But how to combine them? For example, to get TLS and Timeout config together.

Comment: the `Dial` `options` parameter is variadic, you add as many options as you want. If you want an empty config, then pass an empty config. This package appears to use a `nil` config to indicate that TLS should not be used.

Comment: unknown field 'explicitTLS' in struct literal of type ftp.DialOption

Comment: If you want to set `ExplicitTLS` you use the `DialWithExplicitTLS` function. Note that `ExplicitTLS` is a different protocol than what you were first trying to use.

Comment: I intended to set it to false. var tlsConfig = tls.Config{}
 var o = ftp.DialWithTLS(&tlsConfig) don't work either. And I still don't understand how to combine options. Can you clarify pls?

Comment: `ftp.Dial(addr, ftp.DialWithTLS(cfg), ftp.DialWithContext(ctx))`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to make `jlaffaye/ftp` working, but found very old (9 years) library `github.com/webguerilla/ftps` and it works like a charm:

```
ftps := new(ftps.FTPS)
ftps.TLSConfig.InsecureSkipVerify = true

err := ftps.Connect("some_host", 21)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i try use `jlaffaye/ftp` and had to DialWithExplicitTLS

```
// Create a TLS configuration.
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        // Enable TLS 1.2.
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
    }

    // Connect to the FTP server using TLS encryption.
    ftpdialoption := ftp.DialWithExplicitTLS(tlsConfig)

    connt, err := ftp.Dial(FTP_ADDR, ftpdialoption)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
```